# My typescript type declaration file not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I attempted to learn how to publish a TypeScript NPM package for the first time by following tutorials. However, when I used the package in my TypeScript Node.js project, I discovered that it could not recognize the type files for the package. All the other NPM packages I am using have functional type systems except for mine. It appears that the type safety is not functioning properly. Here is the project structure:

I have a file named "easyerrormodule.ts" where I defined my types, for example:

```
export interface comonErrorAttributes{
string?: string[]
number?: number[]
}

export interface commonGeneralErrorRoleAttributes{
role?: string
setRole?: string
}

export interface  stringLengthErrorValueAttributes{
string?: string[]
}

export interface stringLengthErrorShortLengthAttributes{
shortMinLength?: number
shortMaxLength?: number
}
```

I also have this file with my logics called `globaltype.ts`;

```
import { comonErrorAttributes, commonGeneralErrorRoleAttributes, stringLengthErrorValueAttributes, stringLengthErrorShortLengthAttributes, 
stringLengthErrorLongStringLengthAttributes, stringLengthErrorLongStringAttributes} from "./easyerrormodule"

class GlobalErrorClass {
   logics run here
 }

export const errorInstance = new GlobalErrorClass()
```

My typescript config file:

```
 {
 "compilerOptions": {

/* Language and Environment */
"target": "es2015",                                  

/* Modules */
"module": "ES2015",                                
   

/* Emit */
 "declaration": true,                              

// "outFile": "./",                                
 "outDir": "./build/esm",                                

// "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             
"esModuleInterop": true,                             
// "preserveSymlinks": true,                         
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            

/* Type Checking */
"strict": true,                                     

/* Completeness */
// "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      
"skipLibCheck": true,                                
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/globaltype.d.ts"]
 },
 }
```

My package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "errorcatchernode",
 "version": "1.0.4",
 "description": "basic error handling module for node basic projects",
  "main": "build/globaltype.js",
  "types": "build/easyerrormodule.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
   "build": "tsc"
   },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
   "typescript": "^5.0.4"
   }
   }
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: Please share the error as well.

Comment: No error. The package works but it is not listening to type safety. Like, where I am supposed to use string, if I use number, it wont detect that.

Comment: I can now see the error, it is saying the methods have 'any' type. This means that is not seeing the type declaration file. I can also see that my build emit two .d.ts files. I dont know why.

Comment: Make sure your TypeScript compiler is generating the correct type definition files and that the "types" option in your package.json file is pointing to the correct location. You can also adjust the "typeRoots" option in your tsconfig.json file to point to the directory containing your generated type definition files.

Comment: Post the paths and contents of the two .d.ts files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your package has TS exports

```
declare module "errorcatchernode" {
   export interface comonErrorAttributes{ /* ... */ }
   export interface commonGeneralErrorRoleAttributes{ /* ... */ }
   export interface stringLengthErrorValueAttributes{ /* ... */ }
   export interface stringLengthErrorShortLengthAttributes{ /* ... */ }
}
```

but your actual export is

```
declare module "errorcatchernode" {
   class GlobalErrorClass { /* ... */}
   let instance: GlobalErrorClass;
   export default instance;
}
```

Obviously that won't work fine.

What you need if to *reexport* your types

```
// globaltype.ts
export * from './easyerrormodule'
export default new GlobalErrorClass()
```

and change `package.json` to use

```json
  "main": "build/globaltype.js",
  "types": "build/globaltype.d.ts",
```